# How to install all perl modules at once in Ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu, installation, perl-module

I want to install all available perl modules at once in Ubuntu.
Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Even you don't use some of the modules, you still want to install them all ?

Comment: If it does not take too much space (>5 GB or so), I would not mind having them. I work behind a proxy, so setting up an automatic installer is hard, and hand-updating modules every now and then is just too much hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, you probably don't want to.

- Many modules are updated more frequently on CPAN than the Ubuntu repos
- Some modules aren't in the repos at all.
- Many modules will have dependencies you don't need.
- If you ever need more than one environment, it's a problem (although to be fair, this is generally a much rarer occurrence with perl than with other ecosystems).
- `perlbrew` and `cpanm` are lovely and don't require `sudo
- It's not a replacement for proper dependency management as if you ever have a distro upgrade, not all packages may be provided next time.

... however, if you're determined, a very straightforward way would be to look at the output of

```
sudo apt-get search perl | sed -e 's/ - .*//'
```

... and if it's to your liking, run

```
sudo apt-get search perl | sed -e 's/ - .*//' | xargs sudo apt-get install
```

Personally, I'd probably stick a `| egrep '-perl' |` in there, too before the `xargs`, as you might get hits based on the description that don't represent actual perl modules.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of installing everything, why not use [CPAN::Mini](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::Mini) to get them all on your local machine. Then you can install the ones you need when you need them.

Comment: might want to add something about using [Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/), instead of messing with the system perl. It doesn't take much to hose your system mucking with it.

Comment: I was just answering the question ;--) Modern Perl best practices are a different topic.

Answer (score 1):

[Answer based on "Why?" provided in comments]

*Based on my personal experience:*
Almost all perl modules required for serious development are available as ubuntu/debian packages
e.g. Net::DBus perl package is provided by `libnet-dbus-perl` ubuntu/debian package.

You may install ubuntu/debian packages and keeping system itself up to date will update your installed perl modules.